Reading query string in Wagtail
I am new to Wagtail and I am trying to work out how to extract the query string as part of the FormPage model.
In models.py I tried:
def get_context(self, request):
        context = super().get_context(request)
        context['embed'] = request.GET.get('embed')
        return context

But I'm not 100% how to call this in my FormPage model to include this in the email that will be sent when a form is submitted.

Both your code snippets are identical - is that intentional?

@gasman that was a copy-paste error. I have amended the question. I still don't know how to do it so it displays either the query string or HTTP referer in the email that gets sent to me when someone submits a form.
